# Complex animation with CSS and Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll

## Case

I'm working on a small web page that display a jungle (see attached mockup).

[image: Preview project]

On `scroll`, the jungle needs to disappear progressively using some kind of animations.

## Problem

It is the first time I've been asking to do something like that and I honestly have no idea where to start.

The actual page (only in CSS for now) uses absolute positionning in order to recreate that jungle. The jungle is within a bootstrap container using an `overflow: hidden` property (in order to hide edges).

I've been tryin' several plugins ([scrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/), [scrollReveal](http://scrollrevealjs.org/)...etc...) but they all seems to have a problem with my elements being in absolute position.

So, what I'm asking is :

- Is it possible to do?
- Is absolute positionning the way to go to setup jungle elements?
- If no plugin works the expected way, where to start using jQuery for example?

Comment: Hmm I think you're talking about the jungle leaves got pulled to the left on scroll, expanding the view into the real website's screen (like those at the beginning old school movies about tropical countries)? If so I think a `position: fixed;` is more suitable.

Comment: very interesting question , yes its possible , don't go for absolute positioning , use an SVG , Will make your life much easier , use transit.js (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)to animate each element out (at different duration , differt easing .. all to make the effect real )

Comment: @El will make a small demo when iám free :D

Comment: @AvAvt that's exactly what I want to achieve. I do agree with you about the fixed positionning. Will give it a try

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I do not have any SVG, only PNG. Looking to see your demo if you can make it.
Another problem I have is that once this animation ends, the jungle need to be scrollable and show a website.